# IndexOf matching when Unicode 0xFFFD is in the string - bug or feature?

Tags: c#, indexof

In VS2012's C# the following code:

```
string test = "[ " + (char)0xFFFD + " ]";
System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", test.IndexOf("  ") == 1);
```

results in a

```
True
```

printed to console output window. The spaces are separated by `0xFFFD` yet it matches two consecutive spaces. Is that an expected result/feature or a (known) bug?

Comment: Is it only unexpected because there are two spaces in your comparison string?

Comment: You may want to use visible characters other than spaces for the demo.

Comment: Simplifying what you have, your question is why

    `"[ \uFFFD ]"`

contains

    `"  "`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an expected result.  [FFFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) is a "replacement character" in Unicode and is not meaningful in any culture.  [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) ignores any non-meaningful characters in its search:

> Character sets include ignorable characters, which are characters that are not considered when performing a linguistic or culture-sensitive comparison.

Comment: I read that before posting my comment, but wasn't sure if FFFD was ignorable. Thanks for the great info!

Comment: If it were in the ignorable set, wouldn't that be indicated [here](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=FFFD) ?

Comment: @D Stanley: Thank you, I should have read C# manual more carefully. "Strange behavior" of IndexOf(...) costed me (quite) some time isolating and fixing (replacing with RegEx's Replace) random endless loop as the following: `while (test.IndexOf("  ")>=0) test = test.Replace("  "," ");`